# LOCALTIMESTAMP function with precision parameter

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

`SELECT LOCALTIMESTAMP(6)` gives datetime and rounded fractional digits in the seconds field.

Sometimes, fractional digits are not 6, but less, beacuse final `0`-s are truncated, for example sometimes result may be:

```
 2017-01-13 03:08:04.1357
```

Question: there is possible, that all 6 symbols were 0 and result becomes without fractional digits at all, only datetime: `2017-01-13 03:08:04` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
test=> SELECT localtimestamp(1);
       timestamp
-----------------------
 2017-01-13 09:06:04.7
(1 row)

test=> SELECT localtimestamp(1);
      timestamp
---------------------
 2017-01-13 09:06:05
(1 row)

test=> SELECT localtimestamp(1);
       timestamp
-----------------------
 2017-01-13 09:06:05.9
(1 row)
```

I feel safe to assume that the behaviour would not be different for `localtimestamp(6)`.